# anaconda python mysql confusion

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda

Consider the following interaction: I conda install mysql, the installation succeeds, but python denies ever having heard of this mysterious "mysql". I must be being very dense, but in what way?

(base) igor@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal:~/rci$ conda install mysql
Solving environment: done

### Package Plan

environment location: /home/igor/anaconda3

added / updated specs:
    - mysql

The following packages will be downloaded:

```
package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
mysql-5.7.22               |       hef7e34c_0        74.3 MB
krb5-1.16.1                |       hc83ff2d_6         1.4 MB
libntlm-1.4                |       h14c3975_2          33 KB
cyrus-sasl-2.1.26          |       h20670df_3         242 KB
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:        75.9 MB
```

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
cyrus-sasl: 2.1.26-h20670df_3
krb5:       1.16.1-hc83ff2d_6
libntlm:    1.4-h14c3975_2
mysql:      5.7.22-hef7e34c_0
```

Proceed ([y]/n)?

Downloading and Extracting Packages
mysql-5.7.22         | 74.3 MB | #################################################### | 100%
krb5-1.16.1          |  1.4 MB | #################################################### | 100%
libntlm-1.4          |   33 KB | #################################################### | 100%
cyrus-sasl-2.1.26    |  242 KB | #################################################### | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
(base) igor@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal:~/rci$ python
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jun 28 2018, 17:14:51)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import MySQLdb
> > >       import mysql.connector
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're installing MySQL client instead of installing python module. Try to use `conda install mysql-python` (python2) or `conda install mysqlclient` (python3).

On the code, use only `import MySQLdb`.

Check out:

```
import MySQLdb

host = "hostname"
user = "username"
password = "password"
database = "database_name"

db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host,
    user,
    password,
    database
)

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table;")
result = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()

print(result)
```

I hope it was helpful.